# Exit from subfunction of function to main

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Functions() :

    def A(self):
        print "hey"
        self.B()
        return 1

    def B(self):
        print "hello"
        exit(0)


func_obj = Functions()

def main() :

    A = func_obj.A()
    print A
    print "awesome"

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Above is my code. What I'm trying to do is that I want to call `functionA` from the `main()` function and when `functionA` executes `functionB`, I want `functionB` to raise error and exit back to the `main()` function without going back to `functionA`. How can I achieve this? Basically I want the main function to print `"awesome"` after `functionB` exits. I'm not sure what is the correct keyword to look it up.

Comment: hey, check my updated answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hey so after someone pointed out my original answer didnt work i went searching! you can create custom exception classes to achieve what you're looking for!

```
class HaltException(Exception):
    pass


class Functions():

    def a(self):
       print("hey")
       self.b()
       return "1"

    def b(self):
        print("hello")
        raise HaltException("This is an exception error.")

def main():

    func_obj = Functions()

    try: 
        func_obj.a()
    except HaltException as error:
        print(error)
    print("Awesome")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This would then return the following when run :

```
hey
hello
This is an exception error.
Awesome
```

Comment: Return returns to function A :/

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! thank you so much guys!

Comment: silently passing an exception is _almost_ always a bad ideas (except of course for those -  like `StopIteration` - which are explicitely intended as execution flow control).

Comment: Hi guys, sorry, just to confirm, changes was made in above code, and the change is only to send error message "This is an exception error." during raise HaltException correct? and Bruno pointed out that it isnt a good idea to raise an exception without sending an error message?

Comment: Correct. passing exceptions silently can cause lots of issues down the line, so just made it a bit more verbose

Comment: no worries, it was my bad for missing that, props to bruno for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html) - they are actually designed to do just this: [break the normal flow of execution and propagate up the call stack](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions) until someone take care of them (as a last resort, the runtime will catch them, display the error message and a full traceback, and exit).

There are two parts to the process: first raising the exception, then catching it at the right place. In your example it might look like:

```
# declare our own exception type so we can catch  specifically this one
class MyOwnException(Exception):
    pass

def a():
   print("in a - before b")
   b()
   print("in a - after b (shouldn't see this)")

def b():
    print("in b, before raise")
    raise MyOwnException("hello houston ?")
    print("in b, after raise  (shouldn't see this)")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("calling a")
    try: 
        a()
        print("after a (shouldn't see this)")
    except MyOwnException as e:
       print("caugth error {}".format(e))
```

FWIW, your example using `exit()` was really close since `exit()` actually works by raising a `SysExit` exception. The first and main use case for exception is of course error handling, but it's actually really a way to control the execution flow of your program (as an example the `StopIteration` exception is used to signal an exhausted iterator).